# MS Edge blocks script execution when browser is minimized

Tags: javascript, websocket, microsoft-edge

I have a STOMP websocket running which sends pings to the server using setInterval. The pings keep the HTTP session alive which will timeout after 5 minutes.

It seems there are certain situations where MS Edge will pause\block JS from executing. So far I have been able to reproduce it reliably if I close all Edge windows, then open a single Edge window, maximized, with my page loaded. I let my code run for a minute, then minimize the Edge window, and maximize another window. At this point my javascript stops executing until I bring the Edge window back up.

I created a basic example just using setInterval and logging the time. In this example, after you minimize, wait a while, then maximize, you will see a large jump in the timestamps where the JS did not execute. https://jsfiddle.net/9vbs7rkh/

```js
const outDiv = document.querySelector('#out');
const log = (msg) => outDiv.innerHTML =`<p>${new Date()}: ${msg}</p>${outDiv.innerHTML}`;
log("start");
setInterval(() => log("test"), 10000);
```

Strangely enough, if you open the Dev Tools console on the JSFiddle page, the problem will stop occurring across all tabs and I can not seem to re-trigger the issue until I close all Edge windows and start over.

1) Is this documented behavior for MS Edge?

2) Is there a work around to prevent this, so that users are not logged out if they minimize the browser for a short period?

Comment: I've tried your code and followed the steps to try to reprodcue the issue. On my side, when I minimize the edge and maximize it after 10 miniutes, the logging result is normal. Every 10 seconds, it will log the time now. There seems no large jump. Strange. My tesing Edge version is 44.17763.1.0. Could you provide your version?

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait 10 minutes, 1 minute should be good.
I'm on a company computer which I can not update. It is running Edge 41.16299.1004.0. I tried reproducing on my home computer running Edge 42.17134.1.0 and was unable to do so. I will continue trying to reproduce on other computers/version and post updates.

Comment: Hi @user66332 Any solution did you get for this issue?